# Operation involving a quadratic form

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be an inversible $n\times n$ matrix and $x$ some $n\times 1$ vector, now consider the quadratic 
$$
Q=x^T A x
$$
Now consider another $n\times n$ matrix $B=(b_{ij})$ (inversible). I would like to find some matrix operation to convert $Q$ into 
$$
U=x^T C x,
$$
where $C=\left(\frac{a_{ij}}{b_{ij}}\right)$.

Comment: Try for $2 \times 2$ matrices.

Comment: I can't see how.